# display tooltip on a node in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display tooltip to the displayed nodes in the graph using `D3.js`
and how would I display tooltip based on calculation like if scatterplot lies between 2013 and 2014 I want to calculate specific column in csv and disply tooltip for those nodes? How can I do so?

Following is the code I using to display tooltip:

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("fill","blue")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.created_at); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.retweet_count); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(formatTime(d.created_at) + "<br/>"  + d.retweet_count)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
```

Following is the link for my script on Plunker:
[Display tooltip in Scatterplot](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVZaW33yzkggBYHeBGZZ?p=preview)

Comment: Is your question how to display a tooltip or how to calculate the contents of it?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am able to display the tooltip. What I want to do now is if scaterplots are in between like 2013 and 2014 all those tool tips should display the X any Y axis values and the addition of values(i.e favorite_count or retweet_count) in between these values lie.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Given a specific data point, what do you want to display as a tooltip?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Given the specific data point. I want to display Value of X-axis and Y-axis, Addition of all values of favorite_count and retweet_count column values based on the Year on X-Axis i.e if points lie in between 2013 and 2014 I want to display Total favorite_count and retweet_count in that year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution comes in two parts: first, computing the totals by year and then referencing those in the function that creates the tooltip. For the first part, I'm using the [`d3.nest()` operator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_nest):

```
var byYear = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.created_at.getFullYear(); })
  .rollup(function(d) {
    return d.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
      prev.retweet_count += cur.retweet_count;
      prev.favorite_count += cur.favorite_count;
      return prev;
    }, {retweet_count: 0, favorite_count: 0});
})
.map(data);
```

This computes the sums of `retweet_count` and `favorite_count` by year, creating an associative array that you can index into using the year. This is then used to create the tooltip:

```
.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      var year = d.created_at.getFullYear();
      var totals = byYear[year];
      return d["favorite_count"] + " (" + xValue(d) + ", " + yValue(d) + ")" +
        " retweets: " + totals.retweet_count + ", favorites: " + totals.favorite_count;
  });
```

(I've changed it to be a `title` element as the definition of `tooltip` was missing from your example.) This gets the year of the current element, indexes into the array we've created earlier and retrieves the totals from it. The rest is just putting the string together.

Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yyIRnrQQJ92wI44PBEeJ?p=preview).

Comment: Gud Explanation @Lars. Thank you.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FVJek6eo6gYHxZdUZfT1?p=preview I have provides the mouse events after tooltip code. They are not working.

Comment: You were adding them to the `title` element, which doesn't have radius etc: http://plnkr.co/edit/BAOBMDkTvRxPMKu4j0UU?p=preview

Comment: Oh ok! What a silly ques to ask. Thanks a million :)

Comment: In 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8QkDuJIMlO4uXT2c5cvr?p=preview code actually what I am doing is to count the no of `|` signs in csv column `hashtags` and use them as y axis values, and display the graph by same value same value. Can you please guide me that where am I going wrong with this.

Comment: Is this related to the tooltips? If not, it would be better to ask a separate question for this.